# How to grep the all filenames in folderA and (folderB inside folderA)?

Tags: grep, ls, filenames, string

I wanted to list down all the filenames within a **folderA** and another **folderB** inside **folderA** and saved it to a text file. 
The code I used is:

```
ls -1 /home/CSV_XXX/* | grep ^'/home/CSV_XXX' >/home/Lists.txt
```

Suppose I've a folder named **CSV_XXX** in the directory '**/home/CSV_XXX**' & inside it contains:

```
20161010
BDL_EXISTING_CARDS2_20161228.CSV
BDL_EXISTING_COLLATERAL_20161228.CSV
BDL_EXISTING_CUST_ADDRESS_20161228.CSV
.
.
.
```

'**20161010**' is a folder inside **CSV_XXX** with the directory '**/home/CSV_XXX/20161010**' & contains:

```
BDL_EXISTING_CARDS2_20161010.CSV
BDL_EXISTING_COLLATERAL_20161010.CSV
BDL_EXISTING_CUST_ADDRESS_20161010.CSV
.
.
.
```

However, I couldn't get what I want.

During my first attempt, I got:

```
/home/CSV_XXX/BDL_EXISTING_CARDS2_20161010.CSV
/home/CSV_XXX/BDL_EXISTING_COLLATERAL_20161010.CSV
/home/CSV_XXX/BDL_EXISTING_CUST_ADDRESS_20161010.CSV
.
.
.
/home/CSV_XXX/20161010:
```

***without the list of what's in the folder 20161010***

Also, how can I remove the directory '**/home/CSV_XXX/**' if I change my mind to remove it in my list?

just the lists (including **20161010**):

```
BDL_EXISTING_CARDS2_20161228.CSV
BDL_EXISTING_COLLATERAL_20161228.CSV
BDL_EXISTING_CUST_ADDRESS_20161228.CSV
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better using the `find` command

eg

`find /home/CSV_XXX -type f -print`

will list all the files in all the directories recursively under the CSV_XXX directory.

If you only want files matching a pattern then you can do something like

`find /home/CSV_XXX -type f -name '*.csv' -print`

and that will only print filenames ending in `.csv`

If you want to include directories in the list then just skip the `-type f` part.

To remove the directory prefix;

`( cd /home/CSV_XXX ; find * -type f -name '*.csv' -print )`

Comment: Thanks alot ~~~ The script are working fine :) except that `find /home/CSV_XXX -type f -name '*.csv' -print` don't seem to be working. I got the error `ksh: /CSV_XXX/LISTS.txt: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.`

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ls` is not recursive.  You would need to add the `-R` flag for it to descend into subdirectories.  You may find that `find` is a better command to use though as `ls` doesn't give the full path name whereas `find` does by default.

To remove a file from list output, use `grep -v`.

The man pages for `ls`, `find` and `grep` can give you further detail.

Comment: I actually tried `ls -r` instead, it do work... but somehow when I grep it into the text file it doesn't work.